# C++ How to create copy constructor of derived class without using setter/getter

Tags: c++, pointers, getter-setter

I have a small question. I have these classes:

```
class Virus
{
private:
    char* DNA;
    int resistance;
};

class FluVirus : public Virus 
{
private:
    char* type;
};

class HIVVirus : public Virus 
{
private:
    int* undefinedBehavior;
};
```

The scenario is I have class Patient. Patient has been effected by Virus. Sometime, Virus can duplicated them-self and make Patient weaker. So it can be became new object virus with initial variable the same with father virus. (unrelated thing is obj patient can use medicine to reduce the strength of fixed number of virus and become normal after all were died)

Now, I want to create a copy constructor of derived class and base class. The problem is:

1. If the pointer variable (dynamic allocated data) of base class, ie Virus is public, someone said that it violates the encapsulation.
2. If the pointer variable is protected, the derived class can access it, but it still violates the encapsulation.
3. If the pointer variable is private but the base class has protected getter & setter methods, they said "Getters and setters are signs that your class isn't designed in a useful way".

So, if I need a copy constructor, did I violate the encapsulation, and my design has a significant problem?

Are there any available solutions to create a copy constructor in a derived class without violating these problems?

---

To clarify, if I want an outsider to not know the DNA of a virus, I need it private. If I make it protected, someone or maybe me can create a class derived from `Virus` and copy and change information (DNA) of virus. They said that violates the encapsulation because I make a back door to leak information.

If I don't make DNA protected, and I want to make a copy, I cannot copy because the access of a derived class to base class is denied. So, is there any possible solution to avoid protected but can still make a copy?

Comment: Do you want to copy data of base class to data of derived class?

Comment: You mean *derived* class?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy a derived class from other derived class, but they are the same only if the base variable are the same.

Comment: So why don't you call the base class's copy constructor in the derived class's copy constructor?

Comment: One more question: why do you think that when derived class can access m_base (protected member) is the violation of the encapsulation?

Comment: @immibis: I know that I can call copy constructor of base class from derived class but if it is at least protected variable. The problem is I am not sure is this violate encapsulation?
VolAnd: I think encapsulation mean the variable can only controlled by class function not outsider.

Comment: @ThangNguyenXuan Then the base class variable would be controlled by the base class copy constructor and the derived class variable would be controlled by the derived class copy constructor, what's the problem?

Comment: @VolAnd: I think encapsulation mean the variable can only controlled by class function not outsider.
Like: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/why-is-clean-code-suggesting-avoiding-protected-variables
YAGNI, LSP, OCP problems

Comment: In case of inheritance derived class is not really outsider - it is like a son (heir) of base class, so some data can be accessible for derived class, and if there is a need for copying, it is probably the issue of such data

Comment: I see the updated question, and .... I still need clarification: Do you really need copy constructor from base class to derived classes? Can you provide example of code (or use-case description) why you create instance of FluVirus from instance of Virus? And what does the instance of Virus (base class) mean?

Comment: The scenario is I have class Patient. Patient has been effected by Virus. Sometime. Virus can duplicated them-self and make Patient weaker. So it can be became new object virus with initial variable the same with father virus. (unrelated thing is obj patient can use medicine to reduce the strength of fixed number of virus and become normal after all were died)

Comment: Are you looking for a clone interface?  Like so you can do something like `Virus* v = new FluVirus; Virus* v2 = v->clone();` so that the object pointed to by `v2` is also a `FluVirus`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I do not understand restrictions of your task, but it seems that you confused with understanding `protected` data while using inheritance. In general, inheritance allows you to extend the functionality and hence the use of data of base class (protected members) is not a violation of encapsulation - actually this is usage of encapsulation. E.g. you have base class for ***Rectangle*** that store size (height and width or coordinates of vertices - top left and bottom right X and Y), and then you want to create derived class ***Shaded rectangle*** and add color for filling (shading) - it is obvious that the rectangle already has size data and the only additional data is required is color. But if your goal is create something like ***House foundation*** (another class) using the size of ***Rectangle***, there is probably no need for inheritance - just add public size getter to Rectangle and use it.

I understand that for your case you need only one place for `private int*` data - base class:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        m_base = new int(42); // let it be just int in the dynamic memory
    }
    Base(const Base &b)
    {
        m_base = new int(*b.m_base);
    }
protected:
    int* m_base;
};
```

And copy constructor needed only in `Base` class, because `Derived` will have the same data if `m_base` is `protected`.

Just a simple illustration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        m_base = new int(42);
        std::cout << "Base default" << std::endl;
    }
    Base(const Base &b)
    {
        m_base = new int(*b.m_base + 1); // +1 just to see the different value
        std::cout << "Base copy" << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    int* m_base;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void Show()
    {
        std::cout << *m_base << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived  x1; // Default constructor allocate memory and save 42 to it
    x1.Show();
    Derived  x2(x1); // copy constructor of Base class is used
    x2.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

And finally when you need creating `Derived` from `Base`, like:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Base  x1;
    Derived  x2(x1);
    x2.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

The only thing you need is adding one constructor to `Derived` (no data `private int* m_derived;` needed):

```cpp
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(const Base &b) : Base(b)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived \"copy\" from Base" << std::endl;
    }
    void Show()
    {
        std::cout << *m_base << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank for your comment. I did simplify my design. 
I have a class Virus with DNA (pointer) and have FluVirus, HIVVirus, etc. Each Virus has different kind of variable (pointer). For example, FluVirus has char* name (name of FluVirus), ... The problemm is when I want to copy FluVirus. If I use copy constructor, I need access to DNA of Virus (Base class). If it is protected, it is okie. However, some people said it may violate encapsulation and using protected variable is a bad design.

Comment: @ThangNguyenXuan Think over what the need to have base class for all your viruses, perhaps you do not need data in the base class, but only declaration of some methods common for all viruses, in that case base class plays the role of the interface, and does not have data at all - data is defined in each particular class, but in that case you definitely need some getter (method in public or protected interface of base class) for cases when one kind of virus use data of others (Pay attention - others in that case is not a base class, but they are also derived classes from the same base class)

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution. Make Virus aka base class become an abstract class, then doing thing in real class. However, for example, are there any other solutions because I think make the same information of class in the base class is kind of saving code in OOP (?)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from my friend and I think it may help me. So I post it.

Good software design favors composition over inheritance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

The principle are:

1) abstraction should not know about implementation

2) base class should not know about derived class

3) implementation of course has to know about abstraction

so derived class knowing about information base class is normal but that information need to be abstraction and abstraction is some thing to public, not to hide.

So your problem is that you need to hide stuff in base class you should not have such need.

--

It is simple means that if I need to hide information, I need to store information in delivered class. Make the abstract class/interface for usual functions. 
So, instead of

```
class Virus
{
private:
    char* DNA;
    int resistance;
public:
    Virus* clone();
};

class FluVirus : public Virus 
{
private:
    char* type;
};

class HIVVirus : public Virus 
{
private:
    int* undefinedBehavior;
};
```

We can move the private information into derived class

```
class Virus
{

public:
    Virus* clone();
};

class FluVirus : public Virus 
{
private:
    char* DNA;
    int resistance;

    char* type;
};

class HIVVirus : public Virus 
{
private:

    char* DNA;
    int resistance;

    int* undefinedBehavior;
};
```

protected is not safe, is kind of leak info.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
class Virus
{
public:
    virtual ~Virus() = default;
    virtual Virus* Clone() const = 0;
protected:
    Virus(const Virus&) = default;
private:
    std::vector<char> DNA;
    int resistance;
};

class FluVirus : public Virus 
{
public:
    FluVirus* Clone() const override { return FluVirus(*this); }
protected:
    FluVirus (const FluVirus&) = default;

private:
    std::vector<char> type;
};

class HIVVirus : public Virus 
{
public:
    HIVVirus* Clone() const override { return HIVVirus(*this); }
protected:
    HIVVirus(const HIVVirus&) = default;

private:
    std::vector<int> undefinedBehavior;
};
```